# Facebook API. Java Code for Android Project Incorrect.

Tags: java, android, facebook, feed

Having serious problems with a lab and I am not the only one. I have my emulator running fine with all Facebook example apps. FacebookSDK and HelloFacebookSample project all work fine. It is something in the code that is incorrect. All xml, and manifest coding is correct. I am sure it is something in the Java code. It compiles, it prompts a Log-In then it asks about permissions, then it crashes.

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.facebook.HttpMethod;
import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.Session.StatusCallback;
import com.facebook.model.GraphObject;
import com.facebook.SessionState;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
            resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        final TextView newsFeedTextView = (TextView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.newsFeed);

        StatusCallback mCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {

            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                    Exception exception) {

                if (session.isOpened()) {

                    /* make the API call */
                    new Request(session, "/GmitClubsandsocieties/feed", null, 
                            HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {

                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                                    /* check logcat for responce */
                                    System.out.println(response);

                                    newsFeedTextView
                                            .setText(parseDataFromFQLResponse(response));
                                }
                            }).executeAsync();
                }

            }
        };
        Session.OpenRequest request = new Session.OpenRequest(getActivity());
        // request.setPermissions(Arrays.asList("read_stream"));
        request.setCallback(mCallback);

        // get active session
        Session mFacebookSession = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (mFacebookSession == null || mFacebookSession.isClosed()) {
            mFacebookSession = new Session(getActivity());
        }
        // mFacebookSession.openForRead(request);
        mFacebookSession.openForRead(request);
        return rootView;
    }

}

private static String parseDataFromFQLResponse(Response response) {
    StringBuilder responseText = new StringBuilder(" ");
    try {
        GraphObject go = response.getGraphObject();
        JSONObject jso = go.getInnerJSONObject();
        JSONArray arr = jso.getJSONArray( "data" );
        for (int i = 0; i < (arr.length()); i++) {
            JSONObject json_obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);
            responseText.append(String.format("Message: %s\n\n",
                    json_obj.getString("message")));
        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
    return responseText.toString();
}

}
```

This is the logFile:

```
04-24 09:57:28.453: D/AndroidRuntime(2574): Shutting down VM
04-24 09:57:28.453: W/dalvikvm(2574): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2ae0ba8)
04-24 09:57:28.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2574): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-24 09:57:28.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2574): Process: ie.gmit.facebooknewsfeed, PID: 2574
04-24 09:57:28.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2574): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=64206, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {ie.gmit.facebooknewsfeed/ie.gmit.facebooknewsfeed.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-24 09:57:28.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3365)
04-24 09:57:28.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3408)
04-24 09:57:28.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-24 09:57:28.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
04-24 09:57:28.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-24 09:57:28.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-24 09:57:28.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-24 09:57:28.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-24 09:57:28.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-24 09:57:28.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-24 09:57:28.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-24 09:57:28.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-24 09:57:28.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2574): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-24 09:57:28.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at ie.gmit.facebooknewsfeed.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:40)
04-24 09:57:28.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
04-24 09:57:28.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3361)
04-24 09:57:28.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     ... 11 more
04-24 09:57:32.283: I/Process(2574): Sending signal. PID: 2574 SIG: 9
```

Comment: It appears to throw a nullPointerException error on line 5. Says that there is a null value in the "who" field. What part of the code populates `ResultInfo`

Comment: @Nathan may I ask what you mean by "What part of the code populates"

Comment: @Nathan it is feeding from this page, https://www.facebook.com/GmitClubsandsocieties this is the end of a lab in college. It is the last bit and I would love to figure it out.

Comment: @Nathan short answer to question I do not know...just noticed the "ResultInfo" in your question, I would say it is part of the Facebook API that populates it. Session.?

Comment: The API may very well populate the code to `ResultInfo`. That means you need to figure out when you pass user information in `facebooknewsfeed.MainActivity` you check for nullPointers.

Comment: @Nathan Thanks Man, I am at Android properly for under a week, so I think this one I will sadly have to let go. I feel it will be too much for me at this stage & I have many project currently that I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` parameter may not be properly populated. In `onActivityResult` 
add the line
 `Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();`

Comment: afraid not 'the value of local variable bundle is not used'